# Application stops when no inputs are entered

Tags: android, authentication

I followed a tutorial about connecting an android application to an external database.  Below is the code that checks whether the username and password is included in the database. However, when i entered nothing on both fields, the application stops. What should I do? I am new to programming.

login.php

```
//load and connect to MySQL database stuff

require 'config.inc.php';

if(!empty($_POST)) {

//gets user's info based off of a username.

$query = "
        SELECT
        id,
        username,
        password
        FROM users WHERE username = :username
        ";


$query_params = array(':username' => $_POST['username']);


try {

    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

}

catch (PDOException $e) {

    // For testing, you could use a die and message.
    //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
    die(json_encode($response));



}

    //This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's     information is correct.
//we initialize it as false.
$validated_info = false;
//fetching all the rows from the query
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if ($row) {
    //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
    //compare the two passwords
    if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
        $login_ok = true;
    }
    else
       {$login_ok = false;} 
}


    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again
if ($login_ok) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
    die(json_encode($response));
} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

} else {
?>
    <h1>Login</h1> 
    <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
        Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
        Password: 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 

        <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
    </form> 

<?php
}

?>
```

jsonparser.java

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.InputStreamReader;
   import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
   import java.util.List;
   import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
   import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
   import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
   import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
   import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
   import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
   import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
   import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
   import org.json.JSONException;
   import org.json.JSONObject;

   import android.util.Log;

   public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}


public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // Extract data from the response.
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // Open an inputStream with the data content.
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
        String line = null;

        // Build the string until null.
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        // Close the input stream.
        is.close();
        // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // Return the JSON Object.
    return jObj;

}


// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
   }
```

login.java

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;


    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";

SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;


       EditText et_username, et_password;
Button btnlogin;
ImageView pass_visible;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL =
"http://192.xx.xxx.xxx/webservice_phrism/login.php";


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
       public static String filename = "MySharedString";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
    pass_visible = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_visible);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }
    });

    pass_visible.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   et_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    et_password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = et_username.getText().toString();
        String password = et_password.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Name,username);
                editor.commit();
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Dashboard.class);

                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}


    }
```

Comment: You need to include android code. Server side looks ok

Comment: please see modified question sir.

Comment: Is there any log, exception message?

Comment: The easises way would be not allowing users to click the button before entering data

Answer (score 0):

You should control input fields in client side. Try to not show the send button before fields are filled.

Or for example you can check if edittext fields are empty, in this case you push the button and don't call the send function.

EDIT:

Sample code to check if a field is empty.

```
    if (((EditText)findviewById(R.id.editTextID)).getText().toString().isEmpty()){            
        //Message field is empty
    }
```

You can construct a boolean function checking all your fields. When this function returns true you activate your button. Or you don't call the send information function until this described function returns true

Answer (score 0):

You should move code after receiving response from server from DoInBackground to onPostExecute and just pass the response to that method. You can't change state of UI from doInBackground thread, only in onPostExecute and onPreExecute.
 I think starting new intent from that separate thread is causing problems.

Also, showDialog before calling AsyncTask, check if those edittexts are actually != null and from what layout are you referencing them. When user clicks on button to login, then collect input data and pass it to async task.

So, when user clicks Login button, show Dialog, there, on some button in dialog click, call new AsyncTask and pass values of username and password fields. On doInBackground call server and when you get response just pass it to onPostExecute and from there call new Intent.